# On which subset do the partial derivatives of F(z) exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

$F(z)= \left\lvert z\right\rvert + i\left\lvert z\right\rvert^2$

On which subset $\Omega$ of $\Bbb C$ do the first partial derivatives exist.

i.e. $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ exist.

Also, is $F(z)$ holomorphic on $\Omega$ ?

Comment: Everywhere unless origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $F(x+iy) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y) =\sqrt{x^2+y^2} +i(x^2+y^2)$. From this it's easy to see that the partial derivatives exist on $\mathbb C \setminus \{ 0\}$.

Now for where the function is holomorphic. Firstly note that:
\begin{align}
 \partial_xu &= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
 \partial_yu &= \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
 \partial_xv &= 2x\\
 \partial_yv &= 2y
\end{align}

For $F$ to be holomorphic it needs to satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations $\partial_xu = \partial_y v$ and $\partial_y u = - \partial_x v$. Hence we require that:
\begin{align*}
 \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 2y\\
 \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = -2x
\end{align*}
We see that if $x=0$ then $y=0$, but here the partial derivative does not exist. The same goes for $y=0$. Hence we may assume that $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$. Now multiplying the first CR-equation with $x$ and the second with $y$ and adding the equations we have that:
$$
\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0 
$$ 
This equation has no solutions. Hence $F$ is holomorphic nowhere.